# how to fill empty data with today date in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, date

I am sorry for this simple question
I am trying to fill empty data with today's date but I can't find the way to do it.
I tried this code but it doesn't work, maybe I don't use ffill well...
May someone help me? Thank you

'''df_all_patients['sae_vthrombosis_date'] = df_all_patients['sae_vthrombosis_date'].ffill(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))'''

Comment: use `fillna()` instead of `ffill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this
`from datetime import date`
`df_all_patients['sae_vthrombosis_date'].fillna(date.today())`
Please make sure `df_all_patients['sae_vthrombosis_date']` is a datetime

Comment: Thank you very much, can you help me because your code worked very well but then, I got this error when I tried to calculate the difference between two times : ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<M8[ns]'). I guess that's because the dtypes of the column are different?

Comment: please convert all the `datetime` columns using `pd.to_datetime(df['date_columns']) `before subtracting

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":['2020-02-04','2020-03-03',np.nan,'2020-05-05','2020-06-03','2020-07-02']})
df.fillna(datetime.datetime.today().date(),inplace=True)
```